# Chrome extension : onCompleted listener firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, listener, addeventlistener, webrequest

This is my very first question here. I'm developing a basic Chrome extension with the following code.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "commands": {},
    "background": {
        "service_worker":"background.js"
    },
    "action": {},
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
function logURL(requestDetails) {
    if (requestDetails.url.indexOf("&userproof")>0) {
        console.log(`Loading URL: ${requestDetails.url}`);

        fetch(requestDetails.url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log("data::" + data));
    }
    return true;
}


chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    logURL,
    {urls: ["https://website/folder1/folder2/*"]},
    ['responseHeaders']
);
```

The extension is installed in developer mode from a folder, and shows no error upon loading or activation.

Any hint or support is more than welcome, Imrahjel.

When I go into DevTools and open the service_workers panel, I see my listener behaving as needed, I mean it triggers when a HTTP request containing "&userproof" appears.

The issue is that rather than firing one time, it fires dozens of time, eventually until the never if I wait long enough.

I have absolutely no idea with this listener is triggered more than one time, as the targeted HTTP request appears only once in the DevTools console.

I'm actually working on Debian 11 with Brave as a browser. Also tested with standard Google Chrome with no difference.

Comment: That's because you make the `fetch` request to the same url. You can use requestDetails.initiator to skip your own request.

Comment: @wOxxOm : first many thanks for helping. if i get you right I re-fire myself due to the as-is reuse of the request ? If so, can I remove my listener, reuse the request, and then add my listener again ?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

thanks to **@wOxxOm** recommendation to look into requestDetails.initiator, I finally made it work !

For those interested, here is how I managed, it's all about adapting one line in the code given in the original post.

You have to replace the following line

```
if (requestDetails.url.indexOf("&userproof")>0) {
```

with this one

```
if ((requestDetails.url.indexOf("&userproof")>0) && requestDetails.initiator.indexOf("www.website.com")>0)) {
```

With this modification, because fetching from within an extension is not showing the same initiator value, the fetch() will run only for requests originated by "www.website.com".

I'm really new here and wonder how to grant **wOxxom** a deserved upvote or +rep, so in case one can tell me, I would be grateful as the solution is clearly from him.

Thanks,
Imrahjel.